# Битрикс24. Пользователь завершает задачу и после этого автоматически создается следующая для другого пользователя - как это реализовать?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Иными словами, задача в разделе "Задачи и проекты" разбивается на этапы, которые выполняют разные пользователи. Этапы каждый раз однотипные. Вопросы:

1. Как это реализовывается?
2. Это называется настройкой бизнес процессов?
3. Нужен ли для этого тариф битрикса24, называемый "Команда" или достаточно "Задачи+"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Через бизнес-процессы.
2. Да.
3. Нужен тариф команда.